# PyQt5 segmentation fault when trying to save file to disk in real-time app

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, serial-port, pyqt5

I had a completely working, fully-debugged PyQt5 application which 1) accepted streaming real-time data from a USB peripheral, 2) allowed data recording and 3) saved recorded data to disk.  I'm running on top of Ubuntu Linux 17.10.

This application is now broken.  The Linux operating system is not connecting to the USB peripheral dependably.  Kernel updates may be involved.  The problem is complicated, and I discuss it [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30602/usb-uart-half-duplex-problem-has-returned-linux-issue) if you are interested in the details.  I'm trying to fix this problem.  In the mean time, I need to collect data from the device.

My original application allowed full-duplex communications over the USB.  So in the original application, when I wanted to open a QFileDialog to save data to disk, I first issued a command to instruct the peripheral to stop transmitting.  It has been a long time since I wrote this program and I don't remember whether this was truly necessary to avoid a crash, it just seemed like a smart thing to do.

When the OS fails to cooperate, I can no longer do this.  I only have half-duplex communication.  The peripheral must start automatically and must keep running.

My program works as before, right up to the point where I save data.  I open the QFileDialog, I name the file and save it.  The file actually does save to disk, but after that the segmentation fault occurs.

I am trying to devise a work-around for this situation.  Any suggestions are appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: If you're finding debugging dificult, imagine how much harder it will be for people who cannot see your code, cannot test it, and only have the vaguest sketch of what it is supposed to do. Please read the guidance on [ask].

Comment: Normally, I would show my code in more detail.  In this case, that would be unhelpful.  It's about 1,000 lines of PyQt5.  It talks to an embedded system app which is about 500 lines of C and calls hardware-specific libraries.  Is the main issue unclear? I don't know how to debug,or work around, the segfault.  It didn't happen when I had the ability to suspend the peripheral during the file save operation.  I have lost this ability due to an operating system bug.  The issue may be a concurrent stream of Qt events and disk access.  Open to any thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: Unless you produce something approaching a [mcve] it is very unlikely anyone will be able to help you. At the very least, trying to produce one may uncover the solution for you. If not, at least we'll have some idea of how your program works and is designed. I could ask a question like "are you using threading?" but the back and forth is a waste of my (or anyone else's) time when the answer to this (and a dozen other pertinent questions) could be easily answered by seeing some code.